# AngularJS multiple directives ngIf asking for transclusion on !isFocused

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using AngularJS 1.1.5 with JQuery 2.0.3 . 
I receive the following error:

```
Error: Multiple directives [ngIf, ngIf] asking for transclusion on : 


 <!-- ngIf: !isFocused -->
```

I have the following snippet:

main.js:

```
var app = angular.module('test',['ngGrid']);  
app.controller('TestCtrl',function($scope,$http){  
  $http.get("https://my/rest/call".success(function(data){  
       $scope.mydata = data;  
    });   
   $scope.myColumns = [  
      {field: 'name',displayName:'Edit Me'}  
   ];    

   $scope.testGridOptions = {  
    data:'mydata',  
    enableCellSelection:true,  
    enableCellEdit:true,  
    enableRowSelection:false,  
    columnDefs: 'myColumns'  
   };  
});
```

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="test">
    <head lang="en">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
        <script src="jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ng-grid.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="testGridOptions"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just upgrade ngGrid to latest version.

Comment: @Stewie yes I wish that were an option.

Comment: ngGrid up to v2.0.6 defines ngIf directive which collides with the ngIf directive that ships with angular starting at v1.1.5. So you have three options: a) Downgrade angular, b) Upgrade ngGrid, d) Edit ngGrid   and simply replace `ngIf` and `ng-if` instances with `uiIf` and `ui-if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into the same issue where they cannot use the "latest" version of AngularJS.

`ng-grid-2.0.5`

Has a duplicate `ngIf` declaration which causes this error to occur.  By removing the directive the code works correctly.